# Why the contents in the table do not display?

Tags: tables

I made a table in latex and copied the source codes from this page [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) by using the tabularx package, or the tabulary package.

Here is my codes

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l|l |l|}
    \hline
     &X_1&X_2&X_3&\ldots &X_p
    \\ \hline
    Y_1& \hat{\beta}_{11}    & \hat{\beta}_{12} & \hat{\beta}_{13} & \dots & \hat{\beta}_{1N} 

    \\ \hline
     Y_2& \hat{\beta}_{21}       & \hat{\beta}_{22} & \hat{\beta}_{23} & \dots & \hat{\beta}_{1N}
    \\ \hline
   \vdots&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots 
   \\\hline
    Y_J&\hat{\beta}_{J1}       & \hat{\beta}_{J2} & \hat{\beta}_{J3} & \dots & \hat{\beta}_{JN}
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The result is

[image]

It is weird that it only displays the numbers without $\hat{\beta}$.
The contents are supposed to be (please ignore the matrix framework but only look at the contents)

[image]

Could anyone help me to check the problem and fix it? Thank you.

Comment: you must have had error messages from that input. never ignore error messages: tex just recovers enough to check the remaining document, not to generate sensible output

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, there is no any error message. It only generates the weird result.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place TeX would have made many many error messages from that input.

Comment: To be precise Tex gives 84 error messages on a document that just has that table as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because you're not in math mode. Use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{array, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{ | l | l | l | l|l |l|}
\hline
 &X_1&X_2&X_3&\ldots &X_p
\\ \hline
Y_1& \hat{\beta}_{11} & \hat{\beta}_{12} & \hat{\beta}_{13} & \dots & \hat{\beta}_{1N}

\\ \hline
 Y_2& \hat{\beta}_{21} & \hat{\beta}_{22} & \hat{\beta}_{23} & \dots & \hat{\beta}_{1N}
\\ \hline
  \vdots&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
  \\\hline
Y_J&\hat{\beta}_{J1} & \hat{\beta}_{J2} & \hat{\beta}_{J3} & \dots & \hat{\beta}_{JN}\\
\hline
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```